# Template function with variadic arguments compilation issue

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to template function with variadic arguments. The code , inspired by a Codeview article , don't compile at the CreateBook(), need help.

I want to create an object using factory method and template .

```
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class bar
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    static bar<T> CreateBook(Args&&... args)
    {
        return bar<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // Don't compile here
    }

    T get()
    {
        return val;
    }
private:

    bar(const T& t) :val(t) {}
    T val;

};

struct book
{
    string name;
    int phone;
    book(string s, int t) : name(s), phone(t) {}
};

void print(bar<book> k)
{
    cout << k.get().name << " " << k.get().phone << endl;
}

int main()
{
    bar<book> b = bar<book>::CreateBook("Hello World",91520);

    print(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add error message of compiler?

Comment: @R2RT: It says initialization error during return in createBook().

Comment: Mohit and seccpur replies work as expected, but I am not sure which is the right way, yet.

Answer (score 1):

See this code. Your bar constructor should handle pack argument too.

```
template<class... X>
bar(X... x) :val(x...) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to compile your code and I get errors something like `no matching function for call to 'bar<book>::bar(const char [12], int)'` therefore I added `T(...)` to the line marked as `"Don't compile here."` and it worked! Now the code looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class bar
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    static bar<T> CreateBook(Args&&... args)
    {
        return bar<T>(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); // Fixed this line.
    }

    T get()
    {
        return val;
    }
private:

    bar(const T& t) :val(t) {}
    T val;

};

struct book
{
    string name;
    int phone;
    book(string s, int t) : name(s), phone(t) {}
};

void print(bar<book> k)
{
    cout << k.get().name << " " << k.get().phone << endl;
}

int main()
{
    bar<book> b = bar<book>::CreateBook("Hello World",91520);

    print(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why a second T() is required in the return bar<>() constructor?

Comment: @ark1974 I think that the constructor of `bar` was being called with 2 arguments in the previous code but it has just one constructor that takes only 1 argument that is of type `const T&`. So a `T(...)` was required to pass just 1 argument to the constructor of `bar<T>` and the constructor of `T` with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Every problem can be solved by adding one more layer.

First lets isolate the job of Factory. It should do only one task. `Factory` provides an interface on top on the underlying object of type `T`.

```
template <typename T>
class Factory
{
    public:
        // prefer copy and move, if you have C++11
        Factory(Type d) : data(std::move(d)) {} 

        // const getter
        T   get() const { return data; };

        // non-const reference getter, for modifications
        T & get()       { return data; };
    private:
        T data;
};
```

Now lets create a helper function on top of it, to help us manage and allocate objects. The job of this `MakeObject` is to make an object and hand over the object to a manager, i.e. `Factory`. It then returns the instance of that managed object.

```
template<typename Object, typename ... Args>
Factory<Object> MakeObject(Args && ... args)
{
    return Factory<Object>{ Object{ std::forward<Args>(args) ... } };
}
```

Now we can combine the two of them independently, to create something that is desired.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Factory
{
    public:
        Factory(Type d) : data(std::move(d)) {}
        T   get() const { return data; }; 
        T & get()       { return data; };
    private:
        T data;
};

template<typename Object, typename ... Args>
Factory<Object> MakeObject(Args && ... args)
{
    return Factory<Object>{ Object{ std::forward<Args>(args) ... } };
}

struct book
{
    std::string name;
    int         phone;
    book(std::string s, int t) : name(s), phone(t) {}
};

void print(Factory<book> const & k)
{
    std::cout << "[ Factory ] : " << k.get().name << ", " << k.get().phone << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto obj = MakeObject<book>("Hello World", 91520);
    print(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't use the `static` function `CreateBook` because the intent is not clear. If you really want to use `static`, now you have the decoupled code, and it can be implemented and tested independently in the class `Factory`.

Comment: It seems, this is a complete implementation of a factory pattern. I want to learn how to use variadic template functions to accept different objects in the factory method. Thanks for your effort.